# Fetching data with snowflake connector throws EmptyPyArrowIterator error

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use python snowflake connector in my python script (plotly dash app) and today the app stopped working without me changing the code. I tried a couple of things to find out what might be the issue and I even tried to run the example code from [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html) and I got the same error:

code:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute("SELECT col1, col2 FROM test_table ORDER BY col1")
    for (col1, col2) in cur:
        print('{0}, {1}'.format(col1, col2))
finally:
    cur.close()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_connection.py", line 48, in <module>
    cur.execute("SELECT col1, col2 FROM test_table ORDER BY col1")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 580, in execute
    self._init_result_and_meta(data, _use_ijson)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 630, in _init_result_and_meta
    self._result = ArrowResult(data, self, use_dict_result=self._use_dict_result)
  File "arrow_result.pyx", line 42, in snowflake.connector.arrow_result.ArrowResult.__init__
  File "arrow_result.pyx", line 156, in snowflake.connector.arrow_result.ArrowResult._reset
NameError: name 'EmptyPyArrowIterator' is not defined
```

The connection is established, I am capable of creating a table in my database but I cannot seem to query and iterate the data.

I am on `macOS Catalina 10.15.1`, `snowflake-connector-python==2.1.0`, `Python 3.7.0`.

Comment: Can you try changing the SQL to "select 1 as col1, 2 as col2" (leaving out the from ... order by ... ).  You could also try using the DictCursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the Python connector version 2.1.1

pip install snowflake-connector-python==2.1.1

OR

pip3 install snowflake-connector-python==2.1.1

Comment: TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type  this is what I am getting now.

Comment: Some explanation please?

Answer (score 4):

You have to install pyarrow module via

```
pip3 install pyarrow
```

Installation of the snowflake connector does not automatically install it.

Answer (score 2):

Short version: Roll back your snowflake-connector-python to version 2.0.4 by running: pipenv install "snowflake-connector-python~=2.0.4"

Long version:
I checked the commits to the github for the connector, and I saw that they're adding ARROW support. Not sure exactly why arrow_result.pyx is unable to include EmptyPyArrowIterator, but it's wrapped in a try, so it still executes. However, when it gets to the reset function, it can't find the reference and throws an exception.

Comment: Thank you, I upgraded to 2.1.1 they released after your comment and it fixed the issue (they mentioned it in the release notes)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have used
pip install snowflake -- for installing snowflake connector

try with,
pip install snowflake-connector-python

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this a few hours ago in the middle of a long batch job. Interestingly the same job worked jut fine, until all of a sudden it started throwing the "EmptyPyArrowIterator" exception and wouldn't restart. Downgrading `snowflake-connector-python` to `2.0.4` seems to have fixed the problem for now.

Comment: Yes, my script worked fine before as well - they released a fix in 2.1.1 - upgrading to this version fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

For More details what else impact , refer the release document below.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/release-notes/2019-12.html#python-connector-2-1-0-jdbc-driver-3-11-0-support-for-internal-arrow-format

To fix I have install pyarrow at user level

```
pip3 install pyarrow --user
```