# name 'EmptyArrowIterator" is not defined error when calling stored procedure with Snowflake's Python Connector

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**The problem:** When I call a stored procedure in Snowflake using the Python connector an exception is raised that reads:"name 'EmptyArrowIterator" is not defined".

**My goal:** Use Snowflake's Python connector to call a stored procedure and save the return value to a variable.

**What I tried:** [I followed the instructions in this Stack Exchange post but was not successful in resolving the error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307076/fetching-data-with-snowflake-connector-throws-emptypyarrowiterator-error)

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
#my code is long...a dataframe called credentials is defined elsewhere in my code and is not shown below

def logging_sproc(credentials):
    try:
        #import snowflake module and binding method
        import snowflake.connector
        #necesary for passing python variables to statements; note this method is server side
        #so there is no concern about SQL injection attacks
        snowflake.connector.paramstyle='qmark'

        #etl logging variables
        etl_name = credentials.iloc[0]['etl_name']
        etl_guid = credentials.iloc[0]['etl_guid']
        etl_taskname = credentials.iloc[0]['etl_task_name']
        etl_record_count = credentials.iloc[0]['record_count']

        #snowflake variables
        snowflake_warehouse = credentials.iloc[0]['snowflake_warehouse']
        snowflake_account = credentials.iloc[0]['snowflake_account']
        snowflake_role = credentials.iloc[0]['snowflake_role']
        snowflake_username = credentials.iloc[0]['Username']
        snowflake_password = credentials.iloc[0]['Password']
        snowflake_connection = ''
        cs = ''#snowflake connection cursor
        call_logging_sproc = ''

        #call the logging stored procedure
        snowflake_connection = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user = snowflake_username,
        password = snowflake_password,
        account = snowflake_account,
        warehouse = snowflake_warehouse,
        role = snowflake_role)
        cs = snowflake_connection.cursor()
        call_logging_sproc = cs.execute("CALL EDW_DEV.LOGGING.LOGGING_SP(?,?,?,?)",(etl_name,etl_guid,etl_taskname,etl_record_count))
    except Exception as error:
        return error
    finally:
        snowflake_connection.close()
    return  call_logging_sproc

logging_sp = logging_sproc(credentials)
```

**Thank you for your help!**

Comment: Can include the full error that you are receiving?

Comment: Mike, thank you for your reply, that is the full error message: "name 'EmptyArrowIterator" is not defined".

Comment: Does the SP run from within the Snowflake UI?  Perhaps the issue is inside the SP?

Comment: Mike the SP runs perfectly within the snowflake U. I am presented with this issue only 
 when trying to call the SP using the Python connector.

Answer (score 0):

I added call_logging_sproc.fetchmany(1) and the error went away.